How to get product information like product's url, image, etc by provided product id in stencil theme - bigcommerce?
I'm trying to fetch the product information like name, url, image when id is provided in the loop.
I've added other product ID's in custom Fields like below:

My stencil theme code:

My Code:
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
    {{#if name '===' '__alsobought'}}
    
    <span>Coming here..{{ value }}</span>
    <div class="productView-alsoBought-thumbnail-item is-checked" data-thumbnail-product-id="{{value}}">
            <div class="productView-alsoBought-item-image">
                <a class="productView-alsoBought-thumbnail-label" href="{{product.url}}" target="_blank"><img class="lazyload" src="{{cdn 'img/loading.svg'}}" data-src="{{getImage product.main_image 'alsobought_thumbnail_size' (cdn theme_settings.default_image_product)}}" alt="{{product.main_image.alt}}" title="{{product.main_image.alt}}"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}

As explained in my above code, I'm fetching productID's from customField values but not able to get the product Information from the fetched productID.
Can anyone please guide me here? How I can do this in my theme file product-description page.
As suggested, I've implemented fetch method on javascript to get the single product data via graphQL.
    <script>
        fetch('/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer 
           {{settings.storefront_api.token}}'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: `query SingleProduct {
        site {
products (entityIds: [465]) {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      entityId
      name
      addToCartUrl
      
      prices {
        price {
          value
          currencyCode
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

}
}`})
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
    </script>

Now, how I can fetch the product data like the below from graphQL response.

Still the question remains that,

How to fetch the above data from Json.
How I can integrate this data to my HTML code. As creating a HTML node will be longer way to implement this. or is their any other smarter way to do this. My ultimate goal is to add the product information to my html code.


You can get more details about a product via the graphql API. e.g.
https://bigcommerce.stoplight.io/docs/docs/ZG9jOjIyMDczOA-graph-ql-storefront-api-example-queries#get-a-product

Hi @tony how I can use this code in stencil theme file? And how I can integrate this into my above code as this looks on JavaScript side integration. So just little confused that how I can merge graphQl code into with html and theme files. Sorry I haven’t use the graphQl with theme before. Thanks so far with your help

You would have to add JavaScript to make the graphql request for the product id in your custom field, then dynamically add the required HTML into the page.

Hi @tony, I got some success but still I've few issues 1) & 2) if you can help me to get those two resolved would be really helpful. I've updated my question and provided the code but not sure how to reach finish line.  Thanks for your help and time so far


I presume you will be doing your __alsobought loop to get the product IDs to fetch. Ideally you want to create an array of them and just do one request. Maybe have the loop build up a javascript array variable with the product ids inserted into it.



This BigCommerce example shows how to get the json response using response.json(). the next result is in json.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/storefront/graphql/examples#configuring-the-request


That would be the hard bit. As you are potentially adding multiple products you would need to dynamically build the HTML. The lazy way would be to create and add the outer div, then add the rest of the HTML via innerHTML. But the more robust way would be to create and add all the elements to each other.

The json is also quite nested, so it takes some work to pull out the data.
In 10 minutes I'm flying out for 3 days, so will probably not be able to help more for a while. Maybe give chatGpt an example json response and the HTML template you want to put the data in, and see what it does

Thanks for your help so far. I'll implement this and see how far I can go by accessing the Json data & also adding multiple data into the html side. ChatGpt is definitely a good way to do integration with HTML code and Json data

@tom will keep updating this post so if anyone is stuck around GraphQl and html to fetch data then it will be useful to them. Have a safe trip :)
